# Contrary argument on $\inf h(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $h(x_n)$ is nonincreasing and we want to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(x_n)=\inf h(x)$. $h$ is a function. Suppose we use a contrary argument, so we assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(x_n) > h(x)$ for some $x$. Do we need any additional conditions? What if we want to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(x_n)=\min h(x)$ using a contrary argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that with $\inf h(x)$ you mean the infimum of the range of the function, let me call it $m$.

First a general fact:

> **Fact.** if $h(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence (or diverges at $-\infty$), then $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)\ge m$.

The proof is easy. In particular, this holds if $h(x_n)$ is nonincreasing, because then it is convergent (or diverges to $-\infty$).

Let's now prove what you seem to be interested in:

> $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)\ne m$ *if and only if* there exists $x$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)>h(x)$

*Proof.* Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)>h(x)$; we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)> h(x)$ by assumption.
If $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)=m$, then we'd get $m>h(x)$, which is a contradiction.

Suppose instead that $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(x_n)\ne m$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)>m$ (because of the **Fact** above). Let $L>m$ be the limit. Then there exists $x$ so that $L>h(x)>m$, by definition of infimum.

QED

Here I assumed $m$ is finite; do the necessary changes for the case the function $h$ is unbounded below.

The case with the minimum has some additional complications (think to $h$ being a constant function).

Comment: My question is about function of sequence, not sequence. Your proof is not what the original post asked.

Comment: @JohnSmith Just set $a_n=h(x_n)$.

Comment: So you proved $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\inf \{a_n\}$, but did you prove $\inf\{a_n\}=\inf h(x)$? Besides, the OP didn't ask a proof.

Comment: @JohnSmith The symbol $\inf h(x)$ is tremendously ambiguous; I assume it is $\inf h(x_n)$, otherwise the result would be plainly false. My first paragraph is about the issue in the OP's (that is, you) attempt.

Comment: The OP didn't ask whether the statement is true of false. By the way, it might be true under certain conditions. Please see the question carefully.

Comment: @JohnSmith It's your turn to make the question more precise. What do *you* mean by $\inf h(x)$? What is $h$? A generic function?

Comment: @JohnSmith I rewrote my answer with a different interpretation of your ambiguous $\inf h(x)$. But you're not helping.

Comment: I think your argument has some mistakes. You first assumed $\lim h(x_n)\neq m$, then you assumed $\lim h(x_n)=m$. Therefore, a contradiction was found.

Comment: @JohnSmith You asked me to read more carefully your question and I did it. Why don't you spend some time reading carefully my answer? In other words, the two paragraphs starting with “Suppose” are meant to prove the equivalence of “$\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)\ne m$” with “there exists $x$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)>h(x)$”. I reformulated the paragraph for better clarity.

Comment: To make the argument complete, I think the **FACT** needs a proof.

Comment: @JohnSmith You should be able to supply it. It’s a simple application of the definitions.

Comment: When $h(x_n)$ diverges at $-\infty$, what does that mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)\ge m$?

Comment: @JohnSmith Just that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)=-\infty$, of course. Since in this case also $m=-\infty$, this is just a method for not dividing the statement into too many cases.

Comment: Thanks! I greatly appreciate the answer and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The statement $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n) = L$ means that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0,\,\exists n_0\in\mathbb N,\,\forall n\geq n_0,\,|h(x_n) - L|<\epsilon.$$

Its negation is hence

$$\exists \epsilon > 0,\,\forall n_0\in\mathbb N,\,\exists n\geq n_0,\,|h(x_n) - L|\geq\epsilon.$$

In other words, there is some $\epsilon >0$ and arbitrarily large indices $n$ such that $h(x_n)$ is at least $\epsilon$-away from $L$.

Comment: I don't think the argument is applicable to the above case. For instance, you assumed that $L$ is known, but that's not the case. Also $h(x_n)$ is nonincreasing.

Comment: It was my understanding that the question was about proof by contradiction (rather than about proving or disproving the claim per se). What I did was in fact provide the definiton of $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n) = L$ and its negation.